# UITextView detect emergency numbers (112)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

Is there a way to tell UITextView that 112 is also a number which should be detected and made on active link with a possibility to call?

Comment: What's 112?  The talking clock?

Comment: Nope, it's emergency number like 9-1-1, but we have 1-1-2 in EU.

Comment: @RobertVojta I know, my facile comment was designed to highlight that different countries have different emergency numbers...  BTW I'm in the EU and we don't have 112...

Comment: @trojanfoe you have something special in UK as always :) no offense :)

Comment: @RobertVojta No offense taken; who cares about the numbers anyway?  But the OP will have to keep a database of the different numbers for the country the app is being used in, and that's just for starters.

Comment: I need only 112, because it is tourist app intended to be used only in the city where this is the number to call for emergency.

Comment: @Dustin I would like to do so, but somehow my questions aren't answered... Maybe that's because I know how to use google and don't ask dumb questions? 0:)

Comment: @Jaroslav of your 3 other unanswered questions, 2 have been answered pretty well and the other one has a request for more information. You don't HAVE to accept an answer if you don't like it for some reason. But if you get an answer that is at least pretty good and no other answers are forthcoming, accept the answer. It makes you more likely to get help. If you really, really don't want to then answer the question yourself; you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Dustin - read http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23326/161198

Answer (score 0):

Add the notification `UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification` to whatever class has the text view in it. Then in the method check

```
if ([[/*name of textView*/ text] containsString@"112"])
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little but more? I don't get it somehow.
I need any appearance of "112" in my text to become active link to call that number.

Comment: Are you writing the text or is the user writing it?

Comment: What Dustin is talking is `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callEmergency) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:UITextFieldOfYours];` then you have a selector containing Dustin's code: `-(void) callEmergency { if ([[UITextFieldOfYours text] containsString@"112"])
{
    //do something -> CALL THIS NUMBER
}` Like this.

Comment: @NSPunk feel free to post an answer if you think you can explain it better/with more detail. I won't mind ;)

Comment: @Jaroslav Although i don't know how to make a part of a text to become a link to make a call.

Comment: @Dustin haha ;), i think i understood the OP's question but i don't know how to make it, or even if it's possible... but glad you're a good person.